# как при клике в любой точке BODY сгенерировать DIV с случайным цветом

Tags: javascript

```js
//elm
//====================================================
let elm = document.createElement('div');            //
let x = Math.random()*255;                          //
let y = Math.random()*255;                          //
let z = Math.random()*255;                          //
elm.style.backgroundColor=`rgb (${x},${y},${z})`;   //
elm.style.width='100px';                            //
elm.style.height='100px';                           //
//====================================================

 document.body.addEventListener('click', ()=>{//не работает
     document.body.appendChild(elm)
 })
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
    document.body.addEventListener('click', ()=>{//не работает
        let elm = document.createElement('div');            //
        let x = Math.round(Math.random()*255);                          //
        let y = Math.round(Math.random()*255);                            //
        let z = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
        color = 'rgb('+x+', '+y+', '+z+')';
        elm.style.backgroundColor = color;
        elm.style.width='100px';                            //
        elm.style.height='100px';
        document.body.appendChild(elm);
    })
```

```css
    html body{
        width: 100%;
        height: 1000px;
    }
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Comment: вот теперь лайк :)

Comment: @humster_spb Спасибо за замечание. Не стал писать сразу, стыдно за не внимательность стало.

Answer (score 1):

в строчке

```
elm.style.backgroundColor=`rgb (${x},${y},${z})`;
```

лишний пробел после **rgb**

Comment: Там не только в этом проблемы. Во-первых, у body нет высоты, а, значит, клик не сработает. Во-вторых, элемент должен создаваться каждый раз после клика, а у автора вопроса он заранее один раз создался и всё. То есть добавится по клику только один элемент.